# Maximum Product of Three Numbers logic

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x, math

```
'''
Given an integer array, find three numbers whose product is maximum and
output the maximum product.

Example 1:
Input: [1,2,3]
Output: 6
Example 2:
Input: [1,2,3,4]
Output: 24
Note:
The length of the given array will be in range [3,104] and all elements are
in the range [-1000, 1000]. Multiplication of any three numbers in the input
won't exceed the range of 32-bit signed integer.
'''

class Solution(object):
    def maximumProduct(self, nums):
        nums.sort()
        if nums[0]<0 and nums[1]<0 and abs(nums[1])>=nums[-2]:
            res=nums[0]*nums[1]*nums[-1]
        else:
            res=nums[-1]*nums[-2]*nums[-3]
        return res
```

My thought is if the absolute value of the smallest 2 negative numbers are bigger then the 2nd largest positive, those negative numbers should be used in the calc. otherwise, should be the product of the largest 3 nums. Could anyone please take a look and see where of the logic is wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

There are *three* possibilities here:

1. the product of the three largest positive numbers,
2. the product of the largest positive number with the two smallest negative numbers,
3. the product of the three largest non-positive numbers, if there are no positive numbers in the list. For example, the answer for `[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1]` is `-3 * -2 * -1 = -6`.

You do not check for possibility #3 so your routine will sometimes fail.

Also, to distinguish between #1 and #2 you check if the product of the two smallest negative numbers (`nums[0] * nums[1]` if they are both negative) is larger than the product of the second and third largest numbers (`nums[-3] * nums[-2]` if they are both positive). Of course you need to do the checking that there are three positive values, etc. You also need to be careful of the edge case where one or more of the interesting values is zero.

Note that you can reduce all three of my possibilities to just this:

```
nums.sort()
return max(nums[-3] * nums[-2] * nums[-1], nums[0] * nums[1] * nums[-1])
```

You could reduce the overall time complexity of the algorithm by replacing the `sort()` with finding the two smallest and three largest values in the array, but with your array size at most `104` that is not a concern here.

Answer (score 0):

May be using `itertools.combination()` to generate all three possible combination and next check the product of each combination.

```
import itertools

def prod(iterable): #use this funct as the built-in sum()
    x = 1
    for item in iterable:
        x *= item
    return x

comb = list(itertools.combinations(array, 3))
results= []
for item in comb:
    results.append(prod(item))
print(max(results))
```